# PRIMARY KEY must be unique exception on call update

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting an exception when i try to update ma table:

This is the line causing crash:

```
rowsAffected = mDatabase.update(ApplicationDatabase.CHANNELS_TABLE_NAME, values, Channel.DATABASE_KEY_EPG_ID + " = ?", new String[] { values.getAsString(Channel.DATABASE_KEY_EPG_ID) });
```

Here is how i create my table:

```
private static final String CHANNELS_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + CHANNELS_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_KIND + " TEXT, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_INDEX + " INTEGER, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_EPG_ID + " TEXT, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_HASHTAG + " TEXT, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_IMAGE_URL + " TEXT, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_LOGO_IMAGE_URL + " TEXT, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_LIVE_THUMBNAILS + " INTEGER, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_BLENDED_TV + " INTEGER, " +
            Channel.DATABASE_KEY_FAVORITE + " INTEGER);";
```

the logcat:

```
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-51422
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:883)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1565)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at com.orange.programmetv.fr.providers.ChannelsProvider.update(ChannelsProvider.java:109)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:235)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:992)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at com.orange.programmetv.fr.services.ApplicationService.parseChannel(ApplicationService.java:354)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at com.orange.programmetv.fr.services.ApplicationService.parseChannels(ApplicationService.java:339)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at com.orange.programmetv.fr.services.ApplicationService.access$5(ApplicationService.java:327)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at com.orange.programmetv.fr.services.ApplicationService$1.work(ApplicationService.java:321)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at com.orange.programmetv.fr.services.ApplicationService$Request.run(ApplicationService.java:240)
04-05 10:45:27.348: E/AndroidRuntime(18041):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I don't understand why i am getting PRIMARY KEY must be unique exception? I am not doing an insert i am doing an update.

Comment: values contain all elements of my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update you are setting (in `values`) an _ID to a value that is already used by another row.

Don't update the _ID in your values.

### edit

or, your where clause matches more than 1 row and the values contains an _ID. The clause violation occurs because you are setting the same _id to several rows, which is forbidden by nature of a primary key.